# Is it possible to send voice notification to Google Home device

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

We want to send voice notifications to Google Home device from our service when we get some specific events but not sure if it is even supported/possible.

For example, we will notify the user when the cook is almost ready like:
'Hey Ender, your meal will be ready in 5 minutes. Don't forget to take it out'

There are some scripts that claim they send voice notification to Google Home device however they seem to work in the local environment which is not our case.

One of the example scripts is posted on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ifttt/comments/6vj1bu/google_home_voice_notifications/) by @S1lentAssass1n 
https://github.com/GhostBassist/GooglePyNotify

Google mentions some reminder/notification in Google Home documents but I believe it is not what we what.

https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7387866?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Any idea/help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Notifications on the Google Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates) platform are currently in Developer Preview. You can't release an Action that supports them, yet, and they currently on work on mobile devices - not speakers such as Google Home.

This will likely change as it moves out of Developer Preview and into production, but they haven't announced a time frame for this yet.

The solution you cite from Reddit uses the Google Home as a Chromecast Audio device, so requires a (separate) local agent to cast to it. The notes about Google Home refer to the consumer feature from Google that allows you to set notices and reminders - not for other applications.