# Google home: real-time voice notifications using “Say something” method

Tags: python-3.x, chromecast, google-home, google-assist-api, home-assistant

I have a smart google home mini column and I would like it to say notifications or blatantly say: you send a get request to the python flask server with the text "?text=text to say", but...

I have already implemented this through pychromecast (Flask server accepts an http request and uses google cloud tts to form a voice file, upload it to the server, pychromecast starts playing this file), but when the speaker broadcasts sound via bluetooth or chromecast, this message simply does not play.

The most interesting thing is that if you delve into the google home application, then there is such a function, but in a very simplified scale. In the "Routines" section, you can use the "Say something" method and set the time. Thus, it turns out that at a certain time (for example 13:10), he will say exactly what you wrote in this method (for example: "It's time to have lunch!"). And most importantly: even if at this time your speaker is connected via bluetooth or, like a chromecast device, the message will still be played, so also in the native voice of google assistent (US). But the problem is that I don't know how to call this method from outside (assistant sdk, local home sdk, etc.), and ifttt works on the already written text, and I need the column to say the just generated text.But the problem is that I don't know how to call this method from outside (assistant sdk, local home sdk, etc.), and ifttt works on the already written text, and I need the column to say the just generated text.

In general, is it possible somehow (in addition to routines in GHApp) to call the "Say something" method so that the column speaks the freshly generated text in its own voice (when using third-party applications, the voice intentionally changes) and so that the notification is pronounced even when bluetooth or chromecast is active?

Yes I know about it, google removed even the documentation from here.
[Is it possible to send voice notification to Google Home device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674815/is-it-possible-to-send-voice-notification-to-google-home-device)